# Query Members of an Active Directory Group

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, active-directory, security-groups

So in active directory, there is a group called WebSiteUsers that is being used to permit access to a folder I am hosting via IIS.   I was wondering (using DSQuery, ADFind or any freely available tool) how to do the following:

1. How do I query the distinguished name of WebSiteUsers (let's assume
   it is buried a few OU's deep in AD)?
2. How do I query WebSiteUsers to produce a list of users (in human
   readable format) that I can compare against another group to make
   sure all of the people who need access to this resource have been
   added?   For this example, assume WebSiteUsers has a few thousand
   accounts added to it so visual inspection is not an option.    I
   would prefer to use excel to compare the lists of users, so
   exporting a CSV or some sort of text file I can manipulate in excel
   would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the DN run the command `dsquery group -name WebSiteUsers`

---

If you have a domain controller set up for PowerShell (you should; it's awesome) you can run the command `$WebSiteUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter {memberOf -RecursiveMatch CN=WebSiteUsers,OU=Lemings,OU=CorporateBranch,DC=example,DC=com'` and `$WebSiteUsers | Export-CSV` to output to a CSV. You could also use the `Compare-Object` command like so:

```
$WebSiteUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter {memberOf -RecursiveMatch CN=WebSiteUsers,OU=Lemings,OU=CorporateBranch,DC=example,DC=com'
$OtherGroupUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter {memberOf -RecursiveMatch CN=OtherGroups,OU=Lemings,OU=CorporateBranch,DC=example,DC=com'
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $WebSiteUsers -DifferenceObject $OtherGroupUsers -Property Name
```

This will kick out a list of names that are left out of one group or another. (Add `-IncludeEqual` if you want to see everyone.) This will make visual inspection much easier:

```
Jim Bob                      =>                                                                                               
Suzie Q                      <=                                                                                               
Harold Johnson               <=
```

If you want to add everyone that's a member of the other group to the WebSiteUsers group:

```
Compare-Object $OtherGroupUsers $WebSiteUsers | Where {$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'} | foreach{Add-ADGroupMember -Identity WebSiteUsers -Members $_}
```

Might not hurt to add a -WhatIf on the Add-ADGroupMember command to double check it's going to do what's intended.

---

You can also get this list using the Active Directory Users and Computer snap-in. You'll need [RSAT](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887) installed to do this from your workstation, otherwise you can remote in to a domain controller and open it.

Right click on Saved Queries and select New, Query:

[image]

Give it an abitrary name and a short description, then click Define Query:

[image]

Under `Find:` select `Custom Search`. Click on Field and select User, Member Of

[image]

Enter the name of the group you'd like to include and click Add:

[image]

Now you can view this list in ADUC. To export it, click the Export List button. This will output to a tab delimited text file.

[image]

Comment: Duh, thanks for reminding me of this functionality!   Being a linux user I am always looking for ways to do things on the command line (even in windows). Totally forgot that this was an option.

Comment: I think it's much easier on the command line, even in Windows. Not sure if your environment is set up for PowerShell though.

Comment: You will need to either import the AD module into the basic Powershell command shell, or in the administrative tools section of the start menu, find the Active Directory Module for Powershell and open it. (I believe you need to run both of them as administrator.)